# Elementary OS installation failure

Tags: system-installation, grub2, dual-boot, grub, elementary-os

I've been trying for a few hours now and I still cannot find out why I cannot install Elementary OS. Every time I try to install it I get:

> the 'grub-efi' package failed to install into /target/

I am trying to dual boot Elementary with Windows 8.1, I have wiped my SSD and set it as MSDOS to see if it worked, it did not.

I have now used boot-repair in order to see what is wrong, it says:

> The boot of your PC is in EFI mode, but no EFI partition was detected. You may want to retry after creating a EFI partition (FAT32, 100MB-250MB, start of the disk, boot flag).

And after a few seconds I get:

> grub-pc purge cancelled. Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com.

Bootinfo summary: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9488247/

What can I do to make this install work?

Answer (score 0):

Since Elementary OS Luna is based on Ubuntu 12.04 I found that it's quite common problem to install 12.04 with EFI https://askubuntu.com/questions/260297/12-04-2-failed-to-install-grub-efi-to-target .

Anyway, check that you followed steps from here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Yup i followed that, still nothing ;(

Comment: May be you should try [beta](http://elementaryos.org/journal/freya-beta-1-available-for-developers-testers) of Elementary OS or look at ubuntu 14.04.